# can't see disk partition /dev/sdb in linux

Tags: linux, fdisk

I did a successful partition for a new volume `/dev/sdb`. After that I mounted it in `/etc/fstab`.

The thing is that I can't see `/dev/sdb` volumes along with `/dev/sda` volumes using `df -h` command nor with the `mount` command.

Comment: try `fdisk -l`, what output do you get? does your partition appear?

Comment: using fdisk -l I can see the partitions /dev/sdb but when I use df -h to check the mounted location I assigned. they are not there. please advise

Comment: I guess you have created the filesystem on those partitions `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdbX` (ext4 or the type of filesystem you want) right? In that case, `mount /dev/sdbX /mnt` (being X the number of the partition) should mount the partition and `df -h` should display them as mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Are the partitions actually mounted?  Try `mount` to be sure...
Does Linux actually see the new partitions?  Try `cat /proc/partitions` to check...  If not, try `partprobe`.
Check `/etc/mounttab`...  Make sure `/etc/fstab` is correctly written.

Try `fdisk /dev/sdb` or `cfdisk /dev/sdb` to check that the partition actually succeded.  Apropos, you *did* create filesystems with `mke2fs /dev/sdb...`?  Because without a valid filesystem (ext3-4, ntfs, fat) the partions can't be mounted.

Comment: I tried fdisk /dev/sdb and cfdisk /dev/sdb and partitions where there. I already used mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb123 and formatted the partitions successfully.

Comment: when I tried "mount /dev/sdb" it says that couldnt find /dev/sdb in etc/fstab or etc/mtab.

Comment: when I tried cat /proc/partitions .. I could see all the partitions successfully

Comment: when I tried partprobe .. it says the kernal is busy and /dev/sdb is in systems use..

Comment: checked /etc/fstab for the mount destination again and its written well .. I put 0 1

Comment: I didnt know how to check /etc/mounttab..

Comment: why I still cant see voloums using df -h?